# How do I delete object and objects created inside that object?

Tags: c++

I have two classes: `Foo` and `Bar`.

In the `Main` I create 1 `Foo` object. Then I call the method `createBars()` from `Foo`. This method creates 3 `Bar` objects. In the `Main` I want to delete the `Foo` object AND all objects made by that `Foo` object.

How to do this?

Code:

```
int Main()
{
     Foo foo;
     foo.createBars();
}

void Foo::createBars()
{
     Bar bar1;
     Bar bar2;
     Bar bar3;
}
```

Comment: you are not creating in **heap**, no need to delete

Comment: You don't need to delete them, they'll end up, if the function `Main()` goes out returns (ends).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: they'll already be deleted before control flows back into Main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int Main()
{
   Foo foo; // instance created of Foo class
   foo.createBars(); // calling method createBars()

} // automatically, the instance foo goes out of scope, thus getting destructed

void Foo::createBars()
{
   Bar bar1; // create instance of class Bar bar1
   Bar bar2; // create instance of class Bar bar2
   Bar bar3; // create instance of class Bar bar3
} // all the instances bar1, bar2 and bar3 go out of scope and get destructed automatically
```

You are not allocating anything in the **heap**, thus you do not need to de-allocate anything.

[EDIT]

When you are not sure if the constructor/destructor of an object is called, you could always add `cout`s in them and find out.

Here is an example with your code:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {
        std::cout << "Constructor of Bar\n";
    }

    ~Bar() {
        std::cout << "Destructor of Bar\n";
    }
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "Constructor of Foo\n";
    }

    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "Destructor of Foo\n";
    }

    void createBars()
    {
         Bar bar1;
         Bar bar2;
         Bar bar3;
    }
};

int main()
{
     Foo foo;
     std::cout << "After the Foo foo;\n";
     foo.createBars();
     std::cout << "After the foo.createBars();\n";
     return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor of Foo
After the Foo foo;
Constructor of Bar
Constructor of Bar
Constructor of Bar
Destructor of Bar
Destructor of Bar
Destructor of Bar
After the foo.createBars();
Destructor of Foo
```

As Spns pointed out:

The *heap* is a technicality. The important thing here is to *differentiate dynamic vs automatic storage duration*. It is e.g. possible to dynamically allocate memory on the stack.

You need to manually `delete` objects, only when you have **dynamically** allocate them, with `new`. Otherwise, when they get out of scope, they will be de-allocated *automatically*.

Here `bar1`, `bar2` and `bar3` are local variables of the function.

Comment: Thanks, but this was an example. I am working with FreeRTOS and with threads (tasks). If I want to delete a task, I first have to delete the object AND the created objects in that object in that task, right? As in my code, the same tasks can be created again later on. The new objects it makes, have to be empty and unique.

Comment: The *heap* is a technicality. The important thing here is to differentiate *dynamic* vs *automatic* storage duration. It is e.g. possible to dynamically allocate memory on the stack.

Comment: @user3656099 no. You need to manually `delete` objects, **only** when you have dynamically allocate them, with `new`. Otherwise, when they get out of scope, they will be de-allocated. See my edit with the example of the `cout`s. Also, make sure you read Snps comment.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the help. I do understand it better now. I will do my research for dynamic and automatic storage as well.

(btw, why is my post marked with '-5'? Does that mean I have just asked a dumb question?)

Comment: @user3656099 yes, people do that to show you that you should do more research before asking. I will up-vote you, since you are new here, but make sure you search better next time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`delete` is only neccessary when you used `new`.

In your case, you just declare Bar object, no need to delete, they'll "delete" themselfs at the end of the scope of foo.

Comment: Bar objects are local variables.